# Use jQuery to fade image out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following script to fade an image out after 5 seconds:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() { 
    var fade_out = function() {
        $j("#fadeout").fadeOut().empty();
    }
    setTimeout(fade_out, 5000);
});
```

When the image goes away it just disappears. I want the image to slowly fade out over a second or so. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the empty method in the fadeOut callback:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() { 
var fade_out = function() {
        $j("#fadeout").fadeOut(1000, function() { $j("#fadeout").empty(); });
    }

    setTimeout(fade_out, 5000);
});
```

Comment: That worked, one more question though, the content below the image I am fading out jumps when it goes away, is there a way to prevent the content below from jumping? (I do not care if the image that is faded out takes up the space long as it is no visible.)

Comment: Can you show us the html? You have to set the width and height of a parent element. If the next element has the same parent you have to wrap the image in a container with a height and width.

Comment: you could wrap `$j("#fadeout")` into a container with a fixed height

Answer (score 2):

```
var el = $j("#fadeout");
el.fadeOut(1000, function() { el.empty(); })
```

`1000` is the time in milliseconds taken by the effect to complete the fadeOut

You may want to cache a reference to the element (since you need to use it twice)